# Мультиплеер перемещение персонажа

Tags: javascript, node.js, разработка-игр, pixijs

При нажатии на клавиши у персонажа устанавливается вектор скорости, который передается на сервер пока зажата клавиша, на сервере к текущей позиции прибавляется вектор и клиенту отправляется позиция, то есть клиент получат постоянно позицию плеера и позиции других игроков на сервере. Получив позицию перемещает объекты соответственно. Вектор скорости 5 пикселей. Если меньше то получается слишком медленное перемещение, но и при 5 пикселях видно подергивание персонажа, то есть скачки в 5 пикселей. Соответственно при перемещении используется много трафика. У меня ощущение, что я не правильно подошел к реализации.

Если делать перемещение похожее на диабло например, то там передается на сервер только координаты клика, а само перемещение осуществляется на клиенте, потом синхронизируется. Когда так делаю управление выходит намного лучше.

Моя мысль по улучшению такая, вектор скорости например делаю 10 пикселей, получаю позицию куда должен переместится (на клиенте), перемещаю персонажа по таймеру на клиенте прибавляя по 1 пикселю, так же и с аватарами у других игроков на сокете.

Хотелось бы услышать ваши предложения по данной теме.

Накопал вот такую статью http://www.ant-karlov.ru/PlayerIO-interpolyatsiya-ili-udivitelniy-mir-obmana.html
И накопал вот такой исходничек с интерполяцией

```
function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt, controlPt, endPt, T) {
    var x = Math.pow(1 - T, 2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1 - T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T, 2) * endPt.x;
    var y = Math.pow(1 - T, 2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1 - T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T, 2) * endPt.y;
    return ({
        x: x,
        y: y
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/56sZj/
Похоже накопал ответ на свой вопрос, http://igamedeveloper.blogspot.com.by/2013/03/flash.html
 оставлю вопрос открытым может кто то подскажет еще что-нибудь.

Comment: Что за тег `pixijs` вы ввели?

Comment: @Visman Библиотека такая графическая http://www.pixijs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Я не претендую на полный ответ. Но хотел бы предложить направление.

Классический "game loop" как основной принцип работы игрового движка.

```
этап загрузки данных и старта отсчета времени

повторять (до выхода)

     посчитать текущее игровое время

     получить данны по сети

     считать действия пользователя | проверить условия выхода

     просчитать целевое состояние объектов (используя время)

     нарисовать (учитывая время)

     дождаться конца одного шага

 выгрузить данные и закончить программу
```

Плавная анимация это по сути правильно показаные картинки через  ожидаемые промежутки времени. И без аккуратной работы со временем не совсем понятно как ее можно получить.